# Loop in index with multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a loop in my index which references multiple associations that I want to display in a table. At present I have the following, but was wondering if there is a better/cleaner method to this?

**Index**

```
<table>
<% @sales.each do |data| %>
 <% data.selections.each do |selections| %>
 <% data.operations.each do |operations| %>
 <% data.indices.each do |indices| %>
 <% data.snapshots.each do |snapshots| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= data.id %></td>
  <td><%= selections.type %></td>
  <td><%= selections.name %></td>
  <td><%= operations.title %></td>
  <td><%= indices.item_id %></td>
  <td><%= indices.item_name %></td>
  <td><%= snapshots.location %></td>
  <td><%= snapshots.name %></td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
 <% end %>
 <% end %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
</table>
```

As you can see, it's very messy but works fine. I'm hoping there is a better method to this madness.

Comment: what are the associations between these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `data.selections.size == data.operations.size == data.indices.size == data.snapshots.size`. In that case you can do everything in one loop:

```
<table>
  <% @sales.each do |data| %>
    <% data.selections.size.times do |i| 
      <tr>
        <td><%= data.id %></td>
        <td><%= data.selections[i].type %></td>
        <td><%= data.selections[i].name %></td>
        <td><%= data.operations[i].title %></td>
        <td><%= data.indices[i].item_id %></td>
        <td><%= data.indices[i].item_name %></td>
        <td><%= data.snapshots[i].location %></td>
        <td><%= data.snapshots[i].name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```